# How can I add events to angularjs when filters execute?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of tasks and each task has an associated address. I am putting markers on a map when the page loads so our team gets a visual representation of where the tasks should occur. We also have some extensive filtering on the page. How can I update the map markers anytime the filtered data changes?

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in filteredDetails = (details|filterByStatus:page.statusFilter|filterDetailByDate:page.dateFilterFrom+'.'+page.dateFilterThrough|filter:{ColorStatus: page.colorFilter}|filter:{MilestoneIdTaskId: page.milestoneTaskFilter}|filter:{CustomerId: page.storeFilter}|filter:{RepId: page.techFilter}|filter:page.detailFilter)">
</tr>
```

Basically, anytime the filters execute and the table data is refreshed I want to call my code that puts the markers on the map and pass in the filteredDetails as the parameter.

Comment: there should be an event on whatever is triggering the filtering change, like a change event on a search input. given no other option, DOM Mutation events will fire when the table markup changes.

Comment: I'm not following you there. Each of these filters is based on different text box or dropdown selections. What I really want is to be able to execute my marker code when filteredDetails is changed.

Comment: i'm saying there might not be any event on filtering, i didn't see one, but you can correlate other events that trigger the filter change to also execute your marker code. later, there is a table modification event that will be raised just after a filter change. finally, you can use a custom filter function to call the marker maker. something like function filtAll(a){ clearTimeout(filtAll.tim);filtAll.tim=setTimeout(updateMarker,100); return a; }

Answer (score 1):

Just write filter that you add at the end and inside you run your refresh:

```
ng-repeat="detail in filteredDetails = (details|...|filter:page.detailFilter|refresh)"

.filter('refresh', function() {
  return function(input) {
      //refresh the map. input will be filteredDetails
  });
});
```